# Parseval equality with $\int |f|^{1}$

Tags: fourier-transform, parsevals-identity

The famous Parseval equality states that
\[
\int|f|^{2} = \int |F|^2,
\]
where $f$ and $F$ are related to one another by
\[
\int f e^{-2 \pi i r y } dr = F(y).
\]

My question is, whether there is any result for
\[
\int |f|
\]
given its Fourier transform.

Comment: If I remember correctly, if $f \in L^2$, then the $L^2$ norm of $f$ is equal to its Fourier transform norm: http://math.mit.edu/~jerison/103/handouts/fourierint1.13.pdf. For your case of $e^{2 \pi I r y}$, the constant is 1

Comment: If $f \in L^{2}$, then can we say anything about $\int |f|$? (not the mean square)

Comment: Not necessarily, there are many $f \in L^2$ that are not in $L^1$. Let $f = \frac{1}{x} \chi_{[1,\infty)}$ for one example

Comment: How about for those belonging to both spaces?

Comment: You don't even have inequalities of the type $\int |f| \leq C (\int |F|^{2} )^{1/2}$ or the reverse of this inequality.

Comment: I don't think there is any.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for many comments.

Answer (score 0):

There is a general result called the [Babenko–Beckner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babenko%E2%80%93Beckner_inequality) inequality:

$$\left(\sqrt{q}\int |F|^q\right)^{\frac{1}{q}} \leq \left(\sqrt{p}\int |f|^p\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}$$
where $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$.

The equality is only reached in the case $p=2=q$.

In the limit where $p=1$, you might get something like:
$$\max F \leq \int |f|$$
or you most probably remains with the disappointing $$0 \leq \int |f|$$
(I should check whether we can commute the order of the limit $q\longrightarrow \infty$ and the limit of the Riemann sum.)